# hwinfo not found after seemingly successful install

Tags: debian, apt

I installed hwinfo using `sudo apt-get install hwinfo` and the system tells me that:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hwinfo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/32.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 90.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package hwinfo.
(Reading database ... 192008 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../hwinfo_21.6-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking hwinfo (21.6-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up hwinfo (21.6-1) ...
```

Though when I afterwards enter `hwinfo` it says that the `command not found`. `man hwinfo` works, i.e. the manual is shown, however `locate hwinfo` doesn't return anything.

I'm on Debian 8.1

`dpkg-query -L hwinfo` shows that hwinfo lives under `/usr/sbin/hwinfo` and calling this directly works too. So I suppose it is a path issue?

Comment: Try `dpkg-query -L hwinfo` to list what files the package actually installed on your system, and where.

Comment: Thanks @steve. It has been installed under `/usr/sbin/hwinfo`. Should I just add this to my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of a package isn't always the same as the name of any command it contains. You can use `dpkg -L hwinfo | grep bin/` to list the commands it provides (or `apt-file list hwinfo | grep bin/` before installation).

The `hwinfo` package does include a command called `hwinfo`, but it's `/usr/sbin/hwinfo`. The `sbin` directories (`/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/local/sbin`) contain commands that are meant to be used only by root. This doesn't necessarily mean that these commands won't work if called by another user, just that they're unlikely to be useful. The `sbin` directories are normally in the command search path only for the root user.

You can run `/usr/sbin/hwinfo` as a non-root user, but its report is incomplete; it needs root access for some of the information it queries. Therefore run `sudo hwinfo` or `su -c hwinfo` to get complete output, or `/usr/sbin/hwinfo` if incomplete output is sufficient.

You shouldn't add `/usr/sbin` to your `PATH` as most of the commands it contains cannot be usefully run as a non-root user.

Comment: accepted for the extra info on the sbin folder and advice around that. Out of interest, would it be ok to `alias hwinfo=/usr/sbin/hwinfo` or would that cause issues when using the command with sudo?

Comment: @pandita There's nothing wrong with that alias, except that you need to keep in mind that you'll get incomplete information.

Comment: So the alias will not prevent getting the full information when running `sudo hwinfo` then, right?

Comment: @pandita The alias won't even be triggered by `sudo hwinfo`. But anyway what matters is the user running the command, not how the shell was instructed to start the command.

Answer (score 3):

By running `dpkg-query -L hwinfo` you can view all the files installed by this package, together with their location.

So likely installed as `/usr/sbin/hwinfo`.  Add `/usr/sbin` to your $PATH variable if you want to run it with simply the command `hwinfo` rather than the full path+command `/usr/sbin/hwinfo`.